# Set group of objects as background of a scene

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to set the background of a scene. What I want as the background is a group called `stars`. My scene contains a VBox that contains a Label and two buttons. When I add the group to the scene, the VBox is moved, and some of the objects are cut off. I need a way to add the group to the scene without adding it to the VBox. I have tried adding the VBox and the group to another group, but the program does not run at all.

I define the objects to be set as the background in:

```
public static void background()
{

    Group stars = new Group();
    starsLink = stars;

    for (int starInt = 0; starInt < 480; starInt++)
    {

        Circle star = new Circle(Math.random() * 1024, Math.random() * 600, 1, Color.web("white", 1));
        stars.getChildren().add(star);

    }

}
```

and I add the objects to the VBox and set the scene of the stage in:

```
VBox helpVBox = new VBox();
helpVBox.getChildren().addAll(plotLabel, controlsLabel, instructionsLabel, menuButton);
helpVBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
helpVBox.setSpacing(10);

Scene helpScene = new Scene(helpVBox);
helpScene.getStylesheets().add(stellarClass.class.getResource("/CSS/style.css").toExternalForm());
helpSceneLink = helpScene;
```

Comment: hmm, Ok. so do you have some code to share?

Comment: Try adding the group and the VBox to StackPane.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand something like this:

Stage

--Scene

----root (Stackpane or something like that)

-------yourBackgroundGroup

-------yourForeGround (your Vbox with content)

Make sure to add your VBox after the BackgroundGroup or call vbox.toFront() otherwise the background will cover the view :P